# Can I have nodes without any relationship with other nodes in graph database?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

In my case, some nodes don't have relationship with others. Is this allowed in graph database?

Comment: Yes, it's allowed. Please, as recommended before, read through the documentation, and if that doesn't answer your question, download Neo4j community version and play around with it. That should answer most of these basic questions.

Comment: Thank you. InverseFalcon, I am evaluating it and want to get those basic questions cleared before I really try it out. Thank you for your recommendation.

Comment: No problem. You'll learn much more by trying out the free community version, especially because it comes with built in tutorials and example graphs, all accessible from the browser interface. I have a feeling many of your questions will be answered by going hands on here.

Comment: Yes. Those are not good questions.